# Не удаётся подключить библиотеку по работе с Excel-файлами

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-modules

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеки poi.apache.org, это последние 5 библиотек, указанные в build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hand.measurements"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation project(':classification')
    implementation files('libs/commons-io-2.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-3.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-collections4-4.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
}
```

Во время build или компиляции проекта возникают следующие ошибки:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [build]
Error:Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLName
Error:Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\base_android\AndroidStudioProjects\Measurements\app\libs\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
Error:com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
Error:com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLName
Information:BUILD FAILED in 6m 39s
Information:6 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Попытки добавить проект версии библиотеки xmlbeans 3.0.1 и 3.0.2 приводили к тому, что проект всё-таки компилировался, но во время выполнения строки

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
```

возникала ошибка времени выполнения

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
```

Оператор `new XSSFWorkbook(is)` также приводил к ошибке.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы проект запустился и была возможность работать с файлами формата *.xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема возникает в зависимостях библиотеки `Apache POI` и в имеющихся библиотеках Android. В частности проблема вызвана дублированием классов в `xmlbeans.jar`, которые имеются в пакетах `javax.*` предоставляемые Android.

Для работы с Excel на Android предлагается использовать следующие библиотеки, которые были разработаны специально под Android.

- https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx
- https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/

P.S. Данный ответ является переводом. Оригинальный ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38512164/5674568).

Comment: Благодарю, что откликнулись. Пробую с этими библиотеками. Пока что результаты не очень, при использовании первого варианта возникает с *.xlsx форматом возникает ошибка
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: По второму примеру не совсем понятно, библиотеку poishadow-all.jar использовать самостоятельно или с какими-то другими библиотеками, потому что при использовании одной библиотеки проект компилируется, но возникает ошибка, причём как с *.xlsx, так и с *.xls:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/internal/marshallers/ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller

Comment: @PavelSumarokov Пробовали собрать пример в папке poitest второго примера?

Comment: Пробовал, возникает та же VerifyError с классом org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/impl/CTWorkbookImpl

Comment: Ситуация осложняется ещё и тем, что с этими библиотеками не удаётся собрать release-версию приложения, т.е. обфусцировать